# Add content from an external file to the input tokens for parsing

Tags: macros, external-files, parsing

I have a possibly very long sequence of tokens which is parsed by a macro. I would like to be able to read parts of this sequence from external files, if this is possible.

I made up an MWE for this problem. The macro `\myparse` parses a sequence of tokens consisting of `a`, `b`, and `c`. The parsing is terminated by `X`.

Now, I added a further token `i` followed by a file name. I would like to have `i{extern.inc}` replaced by the **parsed** contents of the file `extern.inc`.

The file `extern.inc` contains:

```
aaaabcabcccc
```

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\myparse{%
  \afterassignment\myhandle\let\mytoken=%
}

\def\myhandle{%
  \ifx\mytoken X%
    \let\next=\nextX%
    \else%
    \ifx\mytoken a%
      \let\next=\nexta%
    \else%
      \ifx\mytoken b%
        \let\next=\nextb%
      \else%
        \ifx\mytoken c%
          \let\next=\nextc%
        \else%
          \ifx\mytoken i%
            \let\next=\nexti%
          \fi%
        \fi%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  \next%
}

\def\nextX{}
\def\nexta{(A)\myparse}
\def\nextb{(B)\myparse}
\def\nextc{(C)\myparse}
\def\nexti#1{\input{#1}\myparse}

\begin{document}

\myparse abccbbaaabi{extern.inc}bcX

\bigskip
I would like to have it identical to:

\myparse abccbbaaabaaaabcabccccbcX

\end{document}
```

This gives:

> [image]

How could the macro `\nexti` be modified to get the desired result that the external file is parsed resp. put into the input token sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest strategy is to load the file with `\CatchFileDef` and expand its contents after inserting a new `\myparse`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{extern.inc}
aaaabcabcccc
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\def\myparse{%
  \afterassignment\myhandle\let\mytoken=%
}

\def\myhandle{%
  \ifx\mytoken X%
    \let\next=\nextX%
    \else%
    \ifx\mytoken a%
      \let\next=\nexta%
    \else%
      \ifx\mytoken b%
        \let\next=\nextb%
      \else%
        \ifx\mytoken c%
          \let\next=\nextc%
        \else%
          \ifx\mytoken i%
            \let\next=\nexti%
          \fi%
        \fi%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  \next%
}

\def\nextX{}
\def\nexta{(A)\myparse}
\def\nextb{(B)\myparse}
\def\nextc{(C)\myparse}
\def\nexti#1{\CatchFileDef\temp{#1}{\endlinechar=-1 }\expandafter\myparse\temp}

\begin{document}

\myparse abccbbaaabi{extern.inc}bcX

\bigskip
I would like to have it identical to:

\myparse abccbbaaabaaaabcabccccbcX

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's definitly a good answer for my MWE. I wasn't aware of the `catchfile` package. Still, I'm struggling with applying this answer to my real problem ... something does not work here, but I will need more time to figure out the cause.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Are spaces significant in the string to parse?

Comment: Yes and no. The 'no' is for parsing where spaces should/are ignored. Since the sequence also contains LaTeX text passages, spaces should not be removed in general... Meanwhile, I found my adaption errors. As far as I can see, your answer works for my real application without flaw :-) Thank you very much for your help - I wasn't sure that is could work anyhow...

Answer (score 2):

There is simpler way without usage of `catchfile`. If you are using LaTeX, then replace the line `\def\nexti#1{\input{#1}\myparse}` in your MWE by:

```
\def\nexti#1{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter \myparse \csname @@input\endcsname #1 }
```

If you are using plain TeX then the definition is more simple:

```
\def\nexti#1{\expandafter \myparse \input #1 }
```

Comment: Before I asked this question, I was trying some `\expandafter` things myself, but without luck. Your solution works very good for my MWE! But for my real application, I have problem with the file ending which seems to introduce sometimes blank or `\par` tokens to `\mytoken`. Typically, the external file ends with a `}` (the parsed tokens take parameters) which seems to be the cause of the problem...

Comment: Now, I can recreate the problem for the MWE. Could your LaTeX solution be modified to parse `\myparse abccbbaaabi{extern.inc} bcX` also? Currently, the extra space after `}` is not ignored but causes an extra `C`.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Include next (innermost) level to your `\if\else\fi` tree with the content: `\else \expandafter\ifx\space\mytoken \let\next\myparse \fi`. The reason of your problem: you say `\let\mytoken=%` at the line 4 of your code: this ignores the first space. But if you type `i{foo} ab` then you have two spaces: first one from the end of the file and second one explicitly written.